# Ruby on Rails 4 - FriendlyID ID's based on users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, friendly-id

Is it possible to separate IDs on a per user basis? For example;

I set up devise for users and friendly ID for nice slugs rather than 1, 2, 3 etc.

However, if two users make a todo with the same name, then it's still counted as a duplicate even if that user has never made a todo with that slug before?

I would like the slugs to be unique to each individual user as oppose to unique to the database.

I'm pretty sure this is all the friendly ID code in my application

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for scoped slugs - http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/5.0/FriendlyId/Scoped.html

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  belongs_to :user      
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history, :scoped], scope: :user
end
```

Comment: Ahh, perfect thank you -- I'll read through the documentation now, but that works a treat so thanks for that!